# ModelForm has no model class specified. when use model form

Tags: django, forms, django-models

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\farming\eauth\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "E:\farming\eauth\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "E:\farming\eauth\fwave\farmingwave\views.py", line 14, in contact
        form = ContactForm()
      File "E:\farming\eauth\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 287, in __init__
        raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.')
    Exception Type: ValueError at /about_us
    Exception Value: ModelForm has no model class specified.
```

> my views.py file

```
def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # send email code goes here
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
else:
    form = ContactForm()

return render(request, 'contact-form.html', {'form': form})
```

> my form.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.forms import ModelForm



class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Name'}), label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), label='')
    Phonenumber = forms.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Mobile'}), label='')
```

Comment: show your `ContactForm` class

Comment: okay i am posting my form.py file here

Comment: Add the class by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64785341/edit) your post

Comment: okay i just did

Comment: @GuruTech, please consider adding a descriptive text at the beginning of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't specify a model for the ContactForm to make use of. This usually should be in forms, but irrespective of where you would want it, the form should be like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import YourModel



class ContactForm(ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 
    'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Name'}), label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control 
    col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), label='')

    phonenumber = forms.CharField(max_length=10, validators= 
    [RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form- 
    control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Mobile'}), label='')

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ("name", "email", "phonenumber")
```

if what you intended to do was to just add a form, then your form should look like this.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.forms import Form



class ContactForm(Form):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 
    'form-control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Name'}), label='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control 
    col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), label='')

    phonenumber = forms.CharField(max_length=10, validators= 
    [RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form- 
    control col-lg-12', 'placeholder': 'Mobile'}), label='')
```

Your view should now look like this

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                            send_mail(
              'Subject here',
              f'Name: {form.name}\n Email: {form.email} \n Phone No: 
                 {form.phonenumber}',
              'from@example.com',
              ['to@example.com'],
              fail_silently=False,
              )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render(request, 'contact-form.html', {'form': form})
```

Also, specify your email configuration on the settings.py file as follows:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "Yourdomain <email@yourdomain.com>"
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "yourdomain.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True # if your mail configurations uses TLS/SSL 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "email@yourdomain.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "your_email_password"
```

Note that Yourdomain, email@yourdomain.com, and your_email_password are just placeholders. You should specify your own.

Comment: class ContactForm(model.ModelForm):
NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Comment: You don't have a model defined that you intend using? Then you shouldn't use ModelForm, but instead, Form like I edited my answer to state.

Comment: First, let me understand what you want your contact form to do. If you just want the view to send the contact form details to an email address you specify, then just use the Form from django.forms like I initially stated. Then in your views, get the data from the form and send it.

Comment: i want to create a django form that update user information to database also sends and email to user being successfully registered

Comment: Then that is quite different from the problem you initially stated here. With the last edit I made to my answer, you'd see that the form gets the information, and then sends it to whatever email you specify. What you are asking now, would require that you first have a User field, preferably to inherit from the AbstractUser class and then create a view function for users to signup, and send a notification email to any email you like right in that view. For an app I wrote a while ago , I had to use CRON for that not to delay the app when a user is registering.

Comment: It's only a few seconds, and might be ok for your project.